# Increasing time range of kiali dashboard from 6 hours to some higher number

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kiali

I have installed the istio with kiali from https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/release-1.1/install/kubernetes/helm/istio

But found that on Kiali dashboard I am able to see only 6 hours traffic even when I have stored that data in Prometheus for last 7 days.

So is there any way or property so that I can visualize the dashboard with statistics of last 24 hours or more.

Comment: In theory Kiali should adapt its UI to the storage retention configured in Prometheus, up to 30 days : https://github.com/kiali/kiali/blob/master/handlers/config.go#L91 . If that doesn't work, you should probably open an issue here https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues .

Comment: Thanks Joel, let me check which version of kiali, istio is providing.